# ant-design conflicts with react and crashes app, how to resolve conflict?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-18

I upgraded to React 18.2.0. Now there are times when the application just freezes. The browser page stops responding. What could be the problem?
I have noticed that this happens when interacting with elements from Ant-design 4 that display a popup (Cascader, Select etc).
How can I solve this problem?
I must say right away that it is impossible to update ant-design to the newest version, since all styles are now on less, and in version 5 styled-components

I have no idea what can I do. Maybe use flushsync? But i dont know where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is has a relation to react 18's strict mode, or maybe a bug that Ant-Design had on previous versions, my recommendation would be to try to upgrade your Ant-design version to 5.x (if possible) **or** at least **4.24.12** (to avoid any major updates breaks), please provide a log of the crash or some more details about your code usage if this doesn't help.